# Use media files from a different server just for one custom type

Tags: media

I have Big PDFs on my site so I move it to differ server.
is there any way I can show it n my media gallery popup when I click add feature image or upload images without importing them to my current server just for one custom post type

or as an alternate is there a way to make a tab on the gallery upload page where I can insert the URL of the media

Comment: Maybe this plugin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/external-media/ is useful to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Laloptk but as i said i want to implement it on the featured image part 
i saw many things on internet most of them are useful when we use add media button on editor to insert image or something but  want this feature to be implemented on featured image

Comment: so my main requirement is when I click set pdf then it will open up media modal with the data from server i am not able to find that kind of thing nor any idea if i want to make differ connection in media lib modal